# deploying python dynamic cgi application to bluemix?

Tags: python, cgi, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy a python-based scientific application on IBM's bluemix platform. However, while I can launch the cgi services to host the web pages, the python application behind it doesn't currently run.  The application currently runs on an apache server on rackspace, but I'm try trying launch a newer version for testing.  I tried Heroku, with the same problem that the web pages will be served, but not the python application. But the heroku gist seems to be that Heroku can't serve cgi applications. And there was a suggestion that the Cloud Foundry platform would be able to do so.  The application runs fine locally, so I'm trying to find the right tweak to deploy to Bluemix (or Heroku).

We have the requirements file, and the initial thought is that it's the `procfile` that needs tweaking. Currently it looks like:

```
web: python -m CGIHTTPServer $PORT
```

I've tried launching the application via the worker tag.

```
worker: python weblogo.py

worker: python setup.py
```

even trying to launch the internal files:

```
worker: python /weblogolib/_cgi.py

worker: python /weblogolib/__init__.py
```

Yet none of these methods worked on getting the application behind the web pages to work. Is there another method that we're unaware of?

The application is designed to be served locally with the command.

```
python ./weblogo --serve
```

Does this matter when deploying to a cloud platform?

Rewriting the application to Flask or Django isn't really an option now. Any guidance toward the getting the application launched would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: thanks Alex Da Silva for help with formatting the question!

Comment: I tried to deploy a test script and it seem to be working for me : https://github.com/vmovva/bluemix-python-cgi-sample . Can you take a look my sample and possibly fork , show us a sample app you are trying to deploy?